# I have done scanning of credit card with Io.card sdk but I am unable to find solution for scanning Debit card

Tags: android

I have done scanning of credit card with Io.card sdk but I am unable to find solution for scanning Debit card.Can anybody help me to solve that issue....

Comment: Card.io is unable to scan non-embossed card.

Comment: Yes that's why I am asking for another solution.

Comment: @kiran - if user enable to scan card then there is option for manually enter detail by IO.card you may use it, otherwise you need to buy SDK of OCR as i post detail

Answer (score 0):

As @Nikunj Patel says **Card.io is unable to scan non-embossed card** so you can consider **OCR library** developed by *Yunmai Technolog*y. The OCR SDK can real time recognize credit cards/ debit cards for mobile and PC platforms. The character recognition rate is higher than 98%.

Yunmai Banking Card Recognition SDK (Credit Card Recognition SDK) is a kit that enable developers and integrators to add the OCR (Optical Character Recognition) feature into their software and mobile application. Based on Yunmai OCR engine, this Credit Card Recognition SDK reads images and scanned banking card, and then extract their information.

For more information, you can visit [this link](http://www.ocrsdks.com/ocr-sdk/Banking-Card-Recognition-SDK.html)

Comment: Thank you AD .I will try to implement it.

Comment: I have tried it but its not working for debit plus credit card scanning.Can you explain in brief how it can work.